# Laravel loop collection into small chunks

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to loop the following title of ten into two columns. However, when I try this snippet, it gives me the first and last titles. So what I want is to break the result ten into five of two columns.

```
@foreach ($allbulletin as $bullets)
    @if ($loop->first)
        {{$bullets->title}}
    @endif

    @if ($loop->last)
        {{$bullets->title}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use collection [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-chunk) method

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($allbulletin->chunk(5) as $chunk)
        <div class="col-md-6"
            @foreach ($chunk as $bullet)
                <p>{{ $bullet->title }}</p>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to avoid breaking the results at server side to let the browser perform this job.

This way you can simply loop over your results with a `@foreach` statement:

```
@foreach ($allbulletin as $bullets)
  <div class="content">
        {{$bullets->title}}
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Then you can display it using flex-box (CSS) as in the following snippet.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.content {
  width: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">#1</div>
  <div class="content">#1</div>
  <div class="content">#1</div>
  <div class="content">#1</div>
  <div class="content">#1</div>
  <div class="content">#1</div>
  <div class="content">#1</div>
  <div class="content">#1</div>
  <div class="content">#1</div>
  <div class="content">#1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would have loved to use this snippet but it still comes in a single column and that's the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple `array_chunk()` method:
According to documentations:[array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php), it will automatically make array chunks according to given value

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 5, true));
```

Output will be like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e ) )
```